# How to redirect to specified page after session timeout

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, redirect

How can I redirect the user to the page he has already opened before session time out.

For example the user was open /contactUs.jsp page, then the session time out and he redirects to the login.jsp page, how can I redirect him to contactUs.jsp page when he login again?

Answer (score 1):

You may write a [filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) and check whether a session attribute is exists in the session object. You have to add/set session attribute at the time when user logged successfully.

Answer (score 0):

How are you redirecting to the login page? At that point you should store the originally requested URL somewhere (can be in session, or request param that you pass around) such that you can redirect back there after he logs in again

Comment: I redirect to the login page through a filter, but I can't store the url in the session or request param because session time out, I can store it in local storage, but there are many websites redirect to the page I was already on without using local storage!

Comment: If you forward to the login page instead of redirect (using requestDispatcher.forward), you can retain any attributes saved into the request. In this way you can store the original url as a request attribute and add it as a hidden field in your login jsp

Answer (score 0):

You can put an JavaScript refresh snippet into the response page with the timeout of the session's.

You can also use "Refresh" field HTTP header.

Refer to:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields and search for "Refresh"

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it using a hidden field in the login jsp itself, because the server won't recognize the user since the session has already been invalidated.